# How to use multiple markDown Editor in one page?

Tags: javascript, jsp, editor, markdown

I need to take input from user, which should be **previewed** to user on every onKeyup() event.

By look & feel and in functionalities it should be same like as of "StackOverFlow" text input editor.

I'd done the good research on it. Sharing it for others needy.

Thanks & Regards,

Arun Dhwaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look the complete code: Multiple_Editor_In_One_Page.jsp

Step-1:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>Emotions</title>
<script src="resources/recmJs/Markdown.Converter.js"></script>
<script src="resources/recmJs/Markdown.Editor.js"></script>
<script src="resources/recmJs/check.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/recm/feedBack.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

function showPreviewUsingMarkDownEditor( uid )
{
    var converter = new Markdown.Converter();

    var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter, uid);

    editor.run();
}

</script>

</head>




<body>

<br>
<div id="MarkdownEditor-1"> 

    <p><b>MarkdownEditor-1 in one this page </b></p>

    <div id="write-title" class="wmd-panel">
        <textarea onkeyup="showPreviewUsingMarkDownEditor('-1')" class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-1" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
        <div id="wmd-preview-1" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<br>
<div id="MarkdownEditor-2"> 

    <p><b>MarkdownEditor-2 in one this page </b></p>

    <div id="write-title" class="wmd-panel">
        <textarea onkeyup="showPreviewUsingMarkDownEditor('-2')" class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-2" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
        <div id="wmd-preview-2" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>
    </div>
</div>




<br>
<div id="MarkdownEditor-3"> 

    <p><b>MarkdownEditor-3 in one this page </b></p>

    <div id="write-title" class="wmd-panel">
        <textarea onkeyup="showPreviewUsingMarkDownEditor('-3')" class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-3" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
        <div id="wmd-preview-3" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<br>
<div id="MarkdownEditor-4"> 

    <p><b>MarkdownEditor-4 in one this page </b></p>

    <div id="write-title" class="wmd-panel">
        <textarea onkeyup="showPreviewUsingMarkDownEditor('-4')" class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-4" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
        <div id="wmd-preview-4" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>
    </div>
</div>


<br>
<div id="MarkdownEditor-5"> 

    <p><b>MarkdownEditor-5 in one this page </b></p>

    <div id="write-title" class="wmd-panel">
        <textarea onkeyup="showPreviewUsingMarkDownEditor('-5')" class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-5" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
        <div id="wmd-preview-5" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Step-2:

Crux part is: markdown editor taking three arguments, first is mandatory, 2nd, and 3rd is optional.

In 2nd argumnet, passed the differentiating suffix id.

As you know markdown editor is always looking for `#wmd-input`, `#wmd-preview` elements.

In order to differentiate it in same page, it adding suffix, in the above ids, and pass that suffix as 2nd parameter.

Thats All.

Comment: Crux part is: markdown editor taking three parameters, first is mandatory, 2nd, and 3rd is optional.